# Resolve Bad public atom found when using ffmpeg copy

Tags: video, ffmpeg, quicktime

I have a .mov file with a number of streams both audio and video I'd like to demux (if thats the correct term) into separate files (1 per stream to start with) without loosing quality or resolution

When I use the command

```
ffmpeg -i c:\ffmpeg\VideoFile.mov -c copy -map 0:v:1 -map 0:d Vid1.mov
```

I get a video file Vid1.mov but it throws an error when I try to playback in QuickTime, the original played back fine without errors. During the copy execution the following error is listed

```
fps 600 is too large1 q=-1.0 size= 1455730kB time=01:06:34.72 bitrate=2985.3kbits/s speed= 470x
```

Below is the ffprobe output for the file I'm trying to demux (break into component parts)

`>ffprobe c:\ffmpeg\VideoFile.mov
ffprobe version N-78964-g5061579 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavformat    57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 39.102 /  6. 39.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000026982a1dea0] multiple edit list entries, a/v desync might occur, patch welcome
    Last message repeated 8 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000026982a1dea0] Using non-standard frame rate 250/1
[aac @ 0000026982a22020] element type mismatch 1 != 0
[h264 @ 0000026982a22dc0] Increasing reorder buffer to 1
[h264 @ 00000269850ea500] Increasing reorder buffer to 1
[h264 @ 0000026982a2f920] Increasing reorder buffer to 1
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'c:\ffmpeg\VideoFile.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2015-11-14 19:26:59
  Duration: 01:08:02.11, start: 0.240040, bitrate: 14867 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/bt709), 702x576, 3226 kb/s, SAR 59:54 DAR 767:576, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-14 19:26:59
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
      timecode        : 01:10:08:99
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 74 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-14 19:26:59
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2992 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 0
      creation_time   : 2015-11-14 19:26:59
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264/AVC
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 157 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-14 19:26:59
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:4(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3005 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 0
      creation_time   : 2015-11-14 19:26:59
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264/AVC
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
    Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 157 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-14 19:26:59
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:6(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 5020 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 0
      creation_time   : 2015-11-14 19:26:59
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264/AVC
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
    Stream #0:7(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 157 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-14 19:26:59
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:8(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-14 19:26:59
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      reel_name       : CUSTOM TimeCode track [P 1]
      timecode        : 01:10:08:99
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 8`

**Update: May 4th 2016**
VLC does play the multiple streams without (obvious) issue. I noticed it was mentioned in the comments. I did split the file into its component streams. Mediainfo reports them as being different sizes (height,width in pixels) but all are 25.000fps.

If I playback frame by frame using OpenCV and python the individual streams playback ok (but look a bit jumpy like the frame rate of 25 frames per second isn't correct)

If I playback (using OpenCV and python) the original file I get 1 stream and the message [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000026982a1dea0] Timecode frame rate 250/1 not supported is listed in iPython console to go with the Jupyter notebook I'm using to run the python code

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda tricky. Apparently, the video track you're trying to copy consists of multiple video streams of possibly differing properties stitched together. ffmpeg's MOV muxer (the part that copies over the stream into a new container) does not reliably process such streams.

What you can try is expressly specify the output framerate.

```
ffmpeg -i c:\ffmpeg\VideoFile.mov -r 25 -c copy -map 0:v:1 -map 0:d Vid1.mov
```

Comment: Would the full version of QuickTime allow me to demux the file?

Comment: Don't know. Only use regular QT for occasional use.

Comment: Tried using the -r 25 but still got the error

Comment: Add `-t 01:06:34.68` and check. And another command with `-ss 01:06:34.72` before `-i` and check.

Comment: Whats the significance of the values you selected for -t and -ss?

Comment: The error message you get for large fps happens at `01:06:34.72`. So I'm checking if there's a stitch there. The `ss` for the 2nd commands trims in from there for the 2nd extraction. The error message produced there should be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your demuxed stream may be fine. QuickTime may be confused by the mov extension. Try outputting an .h264 file instead. Verify playback with ffplay. If it plays, you can mux it back into a mov file for QuickTime.

Comment: ffplay is more forgiving of non-uniform streams. Snapchat, for instance, has this facility where they allow you to stitch together multiple videos into one without re-encoding. VLC plays those just fine, but other players like WMP don't decode it correctly.

Comment: Very true. I am making assumptions as to the intended use of the streams. It also seemed significant that the QT error occurred before playback started.